# Get the element attributes from a list in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to list the `type` attributes of the selected nodes, but I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: d.attr is not a function.
```

How to get the attributes?

```
    var svg = d3.select("#grid")
                  .append("svg");

    svg.append('rect').attr('type',1);                                          
    svg.append('text').text('abc').attr('type',2);  
    svg.append('rect').attr('class', 'grid').attr('type',3);

    var list = svg.selectAll('*:not(.grid)').nodes();

    list.forEach(function(d) {
          console.log(d.attr('type'));
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only want get the `type` attribute and not do any D3 modifications, you can use the [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method to get the value of `type`.

```
list.forEach(function(item) {
  var type = item.getAttribute('type');
  console.log(type);
});
```

But doing it d3 style would make your code cleaner. Check out the docs for using [`each`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#selection_each) instead of the Vanilla `forEach`.

```
svg.selectAll('*:not(.grid)')
  .each(function(d, i) {
    var type = d3.select(this).attr('type');
    console.log(type);
  });
```